# (Odoo) How to filter rows/entities saved in a field of a model?

Tags: filtering, odoo

I am trying to filter the images (get images with a certain tag) that belong to a user. The images are stored in a field of the `res.user` model. I tried to solve the problem by using the search() method on the field but as a result, I am getting images that do not belong to that user. Can you give me any advice on how can I solve this problem by using some of the built-in Odoo methods?

```
request.env.user.image_ids.search([
            ('tag_id', 'in', image_tag),
        ])
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
filtered_records = request.env.user.image_ids.search([
            ('tag_id', 'in', image_tag)]).filtered(condition w.r.t field)
```

Comment: what does (condition w.r.t field) means do I need to insert the field name?

Comment: Yes you need to check the condition with your field for example: filtered_records = request.env.user.image_ids.search([
            ('tag_id', 'in', image_tag)]).filtered(lambda l: l.user_id.id == self.env.user.id)

Comment: The filter() method solved the issue, thank you @Himanshu Sharma.